# How can jQuery's click() function be so much faster than addEventListener()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm sure we've all seen the [**site for vanilla-js**](http://vanilla-js.com/) (the fastest framework for JavaScript) ;D and I was just curious, exactly how much faster plain JavaScript was than jQuery at adding an event handler for a click. So I headed on over to jsPerf to test it out and I was [**quite surprised by the results**](http://jsperf.com/click-vs-addeventlistener/5).

jQuery outperformed plain JavaScript by over **2500%**.

My test code:

```
//jQuery
$('#test').click(function(){
  console.log('hi');
});

//Plain JavaScript
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('hi');
});
```

I just can't understand how this would happen because it seems that eventually jQuery would end up having to use the exact same function that plain JavaScript uses. **Can someone please explain why this happens to me?**

Comment: I wonder if what you're seeing here is an artifact of running the same code over and over again in jsperf.  jQuery may only be calling `addEventListener()` once and then chaining all the other `.click()` handlers onto that one call while the plain JS would be calling `addEventListener()` every time - an artifact of how jsPerf measures things - not a measure of typical real world usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in this snippet from jQuery.event.add it does only create the eventHandle once.
See more: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.event.add

```
 // Init the element's event structure and main handler, if this is the first
events = elemData.events;
if (!events) {
    elemData.events = events = {};
}
eventHandle = elemData.handle;
if (!eventHandle) {
    elemData.handle = eventHandle = function (e) {
        // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
        // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
        return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ? jQuery.event.dispatch.apply(eventHandle.elem, arguments) : undefined;
    };
    // Add elem as a property of the handle fn to prevent a memory leak with IE non-native events
    eventHandle.elem = elem;
}
```

And here we have the addEventListener:

```
    // Init the event handler queue if we're the first
    handlers = events[type];
    if (!handlers) {
        handlers = events[type] = [];
        handlers.delegateCount = 0;

        // Only use addEventListener/attachEvent if the special events handler returns false
        if (!special.setup || special.setup.call(elem, data, namespaces, eventHandle) === false) {
            // Bind the global event handler to the element
            if (elem.addEventListener) {
                elem.addEventListener(type, eventHandle, false);

            } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
                elem.attachEvent("on" + type, eventHandle);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. [Running the performance test on multiple divs instead of the same one multiple times](http://jsperf.com/click-vs-addeventlistener/8) gives the expected outcome.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's because internally jQuery really only has to call `addEventListener()` **once**, for its own internal handler.  Once that's set up, it just has to add your callback to a simple list. Thus most of the calls to `.click()` just do some bookkeeping and a `.push()` (or something like that).

Comment: I thought something like this might be happening but when I looked in the code, I couldn't quite figure out where. Do you know where this happens?

Comment: @Aust let me see if I can find the smoking gun.