# native JSmake call to addeventlistener once to attach multiple functions

Tags: javascript

I am using `addEventListener` to add events to elements in my script with fallback to `attachEvent` for IE in a function called `addEventHandler`.

Every time I call to `addEventHandler` function it calls `addEventListener` which decreases the performance and makes even jQuery faster than mine plain JS.

Is there any way to make call to `addEventListener` once? Currently my code looks like this:

```
addEventHandler = function (oTarget, sEventType, fnHandler) {
    if (oTarget.addEventListener) {
        oTarget.addEventListener(sEventType, fnHandler, false);
    } else if (oTarget.attachEvent) {
        oTarget.attachEvent(“on” + sEventType, fnHandler);
    } else {
        oTarget[“on” + sEventType] = fnHandler;
    }
};
```

Comment: How many times are you calling `addEventHandler` that it should make a difference? I have a feeling you're doing something else wrong. That simple function shouldn't result in any substantial overhead.

Comment: 10000 times you know for comparison and i want to know how jquery doing this(a that also uses addeventlistener)

Comment: So you don't have an actual performance issue. Just a theoretical one. Yes, jQuery binds only one generic listener, and puts the actual listeners in `jQuery.cache`. This may provide a *slight* improvement when binding, but will have more overhead when actually invoking the event.

Comment: ...and I have a feeling that your test is flawed in some way. Are you binding handlers to the same element 100000 times? If so, then that would be a problem, as `.addEventListener` guarantees uniqueness of its handlers, but jQuery doesn't do this.

Comment: @CrazyTrain thats 10000

Comment: You're really just missing the point, aren't you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate it *once* instead of on every iteration, since the support or lack of support of an implementation won't change during the runtime:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    addEventHandler = function (oTarget, sEventType, fnHandler) {
        oTarget.addEventListener(sEventType, fnHandler, false);
    };
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    addEventHandler = function (oTarget, sEventType, fnHandler) {
        oTarget.attachEvent(“on” + sEventType, fnHandler);
    };
} else {
    addEventHandler = function (oTarget, sEventType, fnHandler) {
        oTarget[“on” + sEventType] = fnHandler;
    };
}
```

Comment: @user1559763 This moves the function selection to to the initialization (once) instead of on every call. I fail to see how this does not resolve your issue - would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @user1559763 wait, do you want delegation? Like `.on("event","selector"`  ?

Comment: my question was to prevent call to addeventlistener as the jquery do

Comment: @user1559763 You can push functions to an array and then call that array in a for loop for example, I really don't see the use case though.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and the use case is suppose i create a framework tomorrow and some one start testing it as i am testing today and getting beated with jquery then my framework will be closed before its opening ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407960/how-can-jquerys-click-function-be-so-much-faster-than-addeventlistener see the accepted answer if you can expain a little bit to me

Comment: @user1559763 jQuery adds events faster but executes them slower. I can say that I added an event but not actually add a DOM listener too :)